# Entity Framework add-migration when using Vagrant

Tags: entity-framework-6, vagrant, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using vagrant to host my DB and website, but I make changes to my project locally and push changes to the vagrant site. I can run `migrate.exe` to update the DB but I can't figure out how to run `add-migration`? If I run it locally, it says I have pending changes because I have no DB locally? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to update database without use `dotnet ef database update` is execute the command bellow in some default action or startup routine

```
_dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a good idea but what I did was just setup my vagrant SQL instance to accept remote connections and pointed my VS project to the remote SQL. Don't know why that didn't occur to me earlier, =)